# Spring Boot REST API - request timeout?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, timeout

I have a Spring Boot REST service that sometimes call third party services as a part of a request. I would like to set a timeout on all my resources (let's say 5 seconds), so that if any request handling (the whole chain, from incoming to response) takes longer than 5 seconds my controllers responds with HTTP 503 instead of the actual response. It would be awesome if this was just a Spring property, for example setting

```
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000
```

but I haven't had any luck with that. I've also tried extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport and overriding configureAsyncSupport:

```
@Override
public void configureAsyncSupport(final AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setDefaultTimeout(5000);
    configurer.registerCallableInterceptors(timeoutInterceptor());
}

@Bean
public TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor timeoutInterceptor() {
    return new TimeoutCallableProcessingInterceptor();
}
```

without any luck.

I suspect I have to manually time all my third party calls, and if they take too long, throw a timeout exception. Is that right? Or is there any easier, holistic solution that covers all my request endpoints?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to return a `Callable<>` if you want `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000` to work.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Callable<String> getFoobar() throws InterruptedException {
    return new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(8000); //this will cause a timeout
            return "foobar";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If using Java 8, can also use lamba expression: `return () -> {/* do your stuff here*/}`;

Answer (score 27):

A fresh answer for *Spring Boot 2.2* is required as `server.connection-timeout=5000` **is deprecated**. Each server behaves differently, so server specific properties are recommended instead.

SpringBoot embeds Tomcat by default, if you haven't reconfigured it with Jetty or something else. **Use server specific application properties** like `server.tomcat.connection-timeout` or `server.jetty.idle-timeout`.

As commented by [Wilkinson](https://github.com/wilkinsona):

> Setting the connection timeout will only result in a timeout when the
> client connects but is then too slow to send its request. If you want
> the client to wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for a response you will
> have to configure that on the client-side. If you want the server-side
> to only spend a maximum of 30 seconds handling the request there is no
> way to guarantee that as you cannot force the thread that is handling
> the request to stop.

You can also try setting `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout`

Comment: I used all 3 of them for an application that uses `@RestController` and I set very low values for each of them, but they are all ignored. Even if the request takes longer, the page is normally served.

Comment: This does not set a limit on your answer but on how much time it takes to the clinet to send you the request after opening the connection: se here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21914

Comment: so connection/idle timeout is actually request timeout? ))

Answer (score 23):

The `@Transactional` annotation takes a timeout parameter where you can specify timeout in seconds for a specific method in the `@RestController`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional(timeout = 120)
```

Comment: Is there any way to set transactional timeout globally in spring-boot?

Comment: `@Transactional` is meant to handle database transactional behaviour, not to add execution time limit to REST API operations.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest you have a look at the Spring Cloud Netflix Hystrix starter to handle potentially unreliable/slow remote calls. It implements the Circuit Breaker pattern, that is intended for precisely this sorta thing.

See [offcial docs for more information](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html).

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted, it looks to me that implementing the circuit breaker pattern is the best answer. Otherwise, by simply returning a 503 while leaving the request running, you probably waste resources

Comment: You could also use resilience4j https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker. Actual Netflix Hystrix is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 7):

You can try `server.connection-timeout=5000` in your application.properties. From the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

> server.connection-timeout= # Time in milliseconds that connectors will
>   wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. When not
>   set, the connector's container-specific default will be used. Use a
>   value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.

On the other hand, you may want to handle timeouts on the client side using Circuit Breaker pattern as I have already described in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484579/2328781

Comment: `server.connection-timeout=5000` - Deprecated - Each server behaves differently. Use server specific properties instead.

Comment: @Zon do you know the server specific properties for the basic spring boot 2 application?

Comment: @MozenRath, SpringBoot embeds Tomcat by default, if you haven't reconfigured it with Jetty or something else. Use server specific application properties like `server.tomcat.connection-timeout` or `server.jetty.idle-timeout` instead.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using RestTemplate than you should use following code to implement timeouts

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(2000);
    factory.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    return factory;
}}
```

The xml configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"
        p:readTimeout="2000"
        p:connectTimeout="2000" />
</constructor-arg>
```

Comment: what if i want to use timeout just for some specific api's not for all services

Comment: The circuit breaker approach will be better. See https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3

Answer (score 3):

In Spring properties files, you can't just specify a number for this property. You also need to specify a unit. So you can say `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000ms` or `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5s`, both of which will give you a 5-second timeout.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I tried this, and it wouldn't work without a unit.

Comment: Have a look at some of the others answers or the official documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). The question is related to SpringBoot.

Comment: Your link just took me to the source code, which told me that the property type is a java.time.Duration, which requires a unit. I did look at the other answers, and none of them discussed how to specify `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` property in a properties file. They all specified it in code. As far as I can tell, the documentation you linked to supports what I said. So once again. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: See the answer of Danylo Zatorsky. Or any other in the internet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025525/set-timeout-for-specific-async-request-in-spring-boot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006913/increasing-connection-timeout-for-tomcat-in-spring-boot

Comment: So are you saying that I'm talking about the wrong property? My point was that, in my experience, properties that return a Duration need to have units specified. I just used the `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` property as an example because the original questioner used it. Are you taking issue with that claim? Or are you just referring to the correct property to use. Please just answer my question yourself instead of pointing me elsewhere. Your answers have been very vague until this latest one, which finally gives me something more specific.

Comment: Setting it to -1 fixed it for me in the end. That AND returning a `Callable<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>>>`

Comment: Setting what to -1? Are you referring to the `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` property? Or a different one?

Comment: Thx, finally working solution. Unit is needed. Setter method has Duration type.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like none of the answers really solve the issue. I think you need to tell the embedded server of Spring Boot what should be the maximum time to process a request. How exactly we do that is dependent on the type of the embedded server used.

In case of Undertow, one can do this:

```
@Component
class WebServerCustomizer : WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> {
    override fun customize(factory: UndertowServletWebServerFactory) {
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(UndertowBuilderCustomizer {
            it.setSocketOption(Options.READ_TIMEOUT, 5000)
            it.setSocketOption(Options.WRITE_TIMEOUT, 25000)
        })
    }
}
```

Spring Boot official doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-webserver

Comment: This can be even simplified using Spring Boot configuration properties: server.undertow.options.socket.read-timeout=5000

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the Async thread executor for your Springboot REST services. The setKeepAliveSeconds() should consider the execution time for the requests chain. Set the ThreadPoolExecutor's keep-alive seconds. Default is 60. **This setting can be modified at runtime, for example through JMX.**

```
@Bean(name="asyncExec")
public Executor asyncExecutor()
{
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");
    executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(10);
    executor.initialize();

    return executor;
}
```

Then you can define your REST endpoint as follows

```
@Async("asyncExec")
@PostMapping("/delayedService")
public CompletableFuture<String> doDelay()
{ 
    String response = service.callDelayedService();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. setKeepAliveSecods value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Enable and add resilence4j time-limiter

```
resilience4j.timelimiter.instances.myLimit.timeout-duration=1s
```

Then annotate your method -->

```
@TimeLimiter(name = "myLimit")
```