# Spring Boot REST API request timeout

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I have a simple `spring-boot` application which connects with mongodb and expose data. Here is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{coll}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Map> retrieveMongoData(@PathVariable("collection") String collection ,
                                       @RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams) throws Exception{

        Query query = new Query();  
        ........  
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Map.class, collection);
    }
```

Now I need to add request timeouts to the REST API. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout) explains a solution with return `Callable`.

In my case I return `List<Map>` in my controller. How I can implement time-out functionality while complying with my controller.

Comment: Return a `Callable<List<Map>>`? Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: So, do I want to change my controllers' return type or can I implement in a separate way

Comment: Yes changing the controller return type is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

By following the link that you provided, you change the way your requests are processed from sync to async, this can solve your problem, but don't forget that this introduces new overhead ( in case your requests do not really require async processing). I think a better way would be to configure the embeded tomcat directly with a connection timeout, so I suppose by adding: `server.tomcat.connection-timeout=20000` to the `.properties` file, this will make requests have a maximum time of 20s.