# Spring-boot : Set Timeout on REST @ Server Side

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resteasy, websphere-liberty

Spring-boot application deploys on IBM Liberty Server.

Though calling client can set a timeout on the request , I want a timeout to be set on Server side for Incoming HTTP requests.

I have tried `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer setTimeout` but it does not work. 
Am i looking this in a wrong way ? Do i Have to set some property on Liberty Server for expiring these Http Threads ?

Comment: Can you pls provide an answer on how did you accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Your scenario seems to be similar to [Spring Boot REST API - request timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout)

Two things you can try:

1. Use `server.connection-timeout=5000` as suggested by Danylo
2. Use `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000` and return a `Callable` as suggested by Cyril.