# How to add response header when RestTemplate receive request timeout?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I have `RestTemplate` interceptor for set `requestId` to request header and response header but in case request timeout, I can't get response object and can't set `requestId` to response header.

The client that use `RestTemplate` need to know `requestId` for do something when the request timeout but it can't get the value, How to parse `requestId` from interceptor to the client or parse to response header?

thank you

Comment: This can be helpful - https://objectpartners.com/2018/03/01/log-your-resttemplate-request-and-response-without-destroying-the-body/

Comment: @RavatTailor if request timeout, how to do add response header?

Comment: see this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout