# REST API request timeout for services which are always slow

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, timeout

I am working on a project where I have to call a third-party REST service. The problem with the current setup is that service does not return in at least `16` seconds. This response time may exceed more than that.

To avoid the threads waiting on the server, my service has a timeout value of 16 seconds. But that value is not helping. I searched on this and found that the Circuit breaker pattern will be useful. Reference:- [spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout) . I believe this pattern is useful when the service has a slow response a few times. In my case, it is always a slow service.

How can I tackle this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the response from the third party REST service, you have no choise but to wait, but if your request method have other thing to do. You should use Callable Thread to sent request to REST service and let Main Thread to complete the other work first then wait for the Callable to come back.

Maybe you can try to use some Cache like @Cacheable or Redis for this scenario. It may speed up some of the similar request.

Or, just let your request method sent the response back to client first. After that, use AJAX to access the third party REST service from the client side.