# Timeout Long running requests on server side

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I have a Spring Boot application and what I want to achieve is that when my rest controllers take longer to process a request, then simply send an error without continuing to process the request. Is this possible? how do I achieve it in a way without modifying at the controller level but at the application level. This is on latest Spring boot `2.2.6.RELEASE`

Comment: Webflux or MVC?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout

Comment: I am using mvc. so servlet

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using DeferredResult..

See this example:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    DeferredResult<String> test(){
        Long timeOutInMilliSec = 10000L;
        String timeOutResp = "Time Out.";
        DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(timeOutInMilliSec,timeOutResp);
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
            try {
                //Long pooling task;If task is not completed within 100 sec timeout response retrun for this request
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
                //set result after completing task to return response to client
                deferredResult.setResult("Task Finished");
            }catch (Exception ex){
            }
        });
        return deferredResult;
    }
```

> Here request sleep for `100` sec but in `deferredResult` timeout set
>   `10` sec. So after 10 sec you get `Time Out.` response... if you set
>   sleep for less than 10 sec then you will get `Task Finished` response.

[Look](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deferred-result) this for details.