# We are using microservices . How to increase timeout of a particular springboot api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, ribbon

I want to increase the timeout of an API at the controller level. For all API we can do by mentioning the following in my yml file:

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 30000
  ConnectTimeout: 30000
```

But I want timeout increase timeout for a particular API. As it is a long process API. How can we achieve this?

```
@GetMapping(value = { "", "/" })
    public ResponseEntity<Page<DBInventoryMasterEntity>> fetch() {
        Page<DBInventoryMasterEntity> returnList = null;
            returnList = inventoryService.findByCustomerCode();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(returnList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two methods:

1. Return a `Callable<>`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855004/9381213) answer.
2. Use @Transactional annotation which takes a timeout (in seconds) parameter

```
    @GetMapping(value = { "", "/" })
    @Timed
    @Transactional(timeout = 120)  // 2 minutes
    public ResponseEntity<Page<DBInventoryMasterEntity>> fetch() {
        // your code
    }
```

Comment: Will it override ribbon timeout ?