# Use custom restTemplate internally

Tags: spring-boot, http, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I have a SpringBoot 2.6.14 web-app, written in java8, and I have to realize a download of `clob` that is inside my database.

Usually, to export files, I use rest-controller like follows:

```
@GetMapping("/upload/{id}")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK",content = @Content (schema = @Schema (type = "string", format = "byte")))
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getUpload(@PathVariable("id") Integer id)
        throws Exception {
    
    try {
        byte[] result = someService.convertClobToByte(id);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "upload.xlsx");
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                   .headers(headers)
                   .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
                   .body(result);
    } catch (ServiceException se) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, se.getMessage(), se);
    }
}
```

Now the customer ask me to set a time limit. if the download takes more than 30 seconds I have to thrown an Exception and block tthe operation.

Now he said me that to create a custom restTemplate like follow I found googling around:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
       .setConnectTimeout(...)
       .setReadTimeout(...)
       .build();
 }
}
```

Now I don't know how to use it inside my controller.. Usually I use restTemplate to call API on other machine using, for example, the `exchange` method.

What I should place as `URI` or `entity` inside my exchange method? Maybe should I use this other version of snippet found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

 @Bean
 public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
 }

 private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
   HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
   factory.setReadTimeout(2000);
   factory.setConnectTimeout(2000);
   return factory;
 }
}
```

Will the above code apply the timeout to all HTTP Connection? What is the best way to do this kind of job?

Comment: Yes you are right about usage of `restTemplate`. You just have to set a time out of your controller method a related answers to this topic you can find [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout]